# Any IDE's plugin to get a value of a feature flag from the DB without having to copy paste and run the query each time?

Tags: database, spring-boot, intellij-idea, spring-data, intellij-plugin

We have a huge table with customer feature flags, most of the time the key is a String attribute and we would like to know its value in the productions DB.
So we need copy the string from the code +  writing down the query + running the query

Maybe 20 times a day. Any shortcuts for selecting the text and right click to run a predefined query with just injecting the selected text ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the [Live Templates](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/using-live-templates.html#live_templates_types). You can create your query with [your custom-defined variable(s)](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/template-variables.html) which you would insert for each query you create with the template.